# Intellij idea - any tool to transform xml beans to autowiing annotations for spring?

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I am new to spring and trying to teach myself.
I wonder if there is any tool to transform xml beans to autowiring annotations .

How to do that manually ( apart from setup) with example is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so that any tool exist, maybe I'm wrong..
If I well understand you want to mix xml and java. If yes you should have beans inside xml and include `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` directly in bean configuration file. And then you could be able autowired bean via `@Autowired`, and it can be applied on setter method, constructor or a field.

In my opinion better start learning with annotation because currently most of companies using spring with annotation only old projects contain xml configuration. I know is good to know everything :)

--> well If you want to move configuration to annotation you can do it in simply way

1st create configuration class

```
@Configuration  
@ComponentScan 
public class SampleConfiguration {...}
```

then create beans like below

```
@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    // here you can use BasicDataSource, DataSourceBuilder, DriverManagerDataSource or other class 
    // for example
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(...);
    dataSource.setUrl(...);
    dataSource.setUsername(...);
    dataSource.setPassword(...);
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    jdbcTemplate.setResultsMapCaseInsensitive(true);
    return jdbcTemplate;
}
```

another way of creating beans is creating class with annotation `@Component`, `@Repository`, `@Service`, `@Controller` but be sure the main class is the highest hierarchy of directory or just provide in `@ComponentScan` base package :)

Comment: Thanks Damian for your response. What i mean is there a way for example to get rid of the xml below and rely on Autowiring instead ?<bean id ="jdbcTemplate" class ="org.springframework........"  ... Ref="dataSource"/> <bean id="dataSource" class="Myclass"...... Ref="getDataSource"/>

Comment: I edited answer above because here my message contains too much characters

Comment: I hope this will be helpful 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html
and in **core** you should find everything what you need 
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.x/spring-framework-reference/index.html